# General word for the property of something that describes how full something is

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a general word.  A few examples to help illustrate:

- If a class has 10 spots and 4 people have registered, the class' ____ is 4.
- If you're filling up a container of unknown capacity and it takes a while and someone asks on your progress, they may inquire about the container's current ____.
- If a battery or capacitor is 50% charged, its ____ is half.
- If a progress meter or a loading indicator hasn't progressed very far, its ____ is low.

The closest I've come up with is "fullness" (or "level" in the container example, though that's usually used along with a reference to the thing filling the container, as in "water level" or "the level of the dirt").  But those don't seem quite right.  I think something more generic that could be used in these and other similar cases is what I'm after - any place you have a total and you're after the current amount filled, whether or not the total or the current amount are specific numbers or general amounts (like nearly empty or nearly full).

A closely related word to content might be proportion. But this doesn't capture the specific emphasis on "how close to complete fullness" I'm after, although it does speak to the relation of the part to the whole, which is an essential element.

Comment: I would go with ["capacity"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/capacity), but I am afraid the question will get closed for "lack of research"

Comment: I'd guess that this is a lexical gap. The usual questions would be "How many people have registered so far?" /  "What's the take-up like?" // "How full is it?"

Comment: @Cascabel the word capacity came to mind, but I feel that can mean "how many/much can it hold total" and so could be ambiguous.  As in "full to capacity".

Comment: I am not sure there is a perfect word to describe this... The inverse seems easier: the class has six spots _free_ (or six spots of _free space_ ). In a technical context this is often referred to as the _size_ of an entity, but feel this would be confusing in general conversation.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It may be a lexical problem.  However, if such a word does exist, I don't know that the questions you mentioned would be any more or less usual (unless the word is a rarely used one).  But if the word exists, I don't see any lexical gap in inserting it into the questions in the OP.  If such a word doesn't exist, it should :)

Comment: Well, as you say, the word will be different depending on what you're filling. For something like a container it can be *level, filling height, filling level, depth of fill, depth of filling, filling depth, height of fill, height of filling*, or whatever. For a school class it could be something completely different like *attendance*. The more stuff of different nature you're trying to find a hypernym for, the less specific that hypernym has to become. The only hypernym that covers all stuff is, well, *stuff*.

Comment: @RegDwigнt different words could definitely be used for different cases.  I've edited the title and question to clarify that what I'm after is a generally applicable term, which I should've specified with the initial post.

Comment: I would go with "amount."

Comment: You say "I'm looking for a general word." That word does not exist. Not all the blanks can be completed in an an idiomatic way. -- 1 If a class has 10 spots and 4 people have registered, the **current enrollment for the class is 4**. -- 2 If you're filling up a container of unknown capacity and it takes a while and someone asks on your progress, they may **ask about how much there is in it currently.**" -- 3 If a battery or capacitor is 50% charged, its **level of charge** is half. -- 4 If a progress meter or a loading indicator hasn't progressed very far, **its needle is still low.**

Comment: One word that works in all those examples is "content." How would that not work for you?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin "If a class has 10 spots and 4 people have registered, the class' content is 4." This doesn't sound right, somehow. Consider a container 3/4 of the way full of water. We wouldn't say its content is 3/4.  We'd say its content is water. MW's definition "the amount of specified material contained" lacks the idea of relation to the total capacity.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin a closely related word to content might be proportion.  But this doesn't capture the specific emphasis on "how close to complete fullness" I'm after, although it does speak to the relation of the part to the whole, which is an essential element.

Comment: @jinglesthula Ah… could you edit the Question to include those clues?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin you bet - good suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

How about extent?

The extent of the class is four students.

The extent of the container's contents is halfway.

The extent of the battery's charge is halfway.

The extent of the progress is low.

Comment: I think both "extent" and "volume" could fit all four sentences.

Answer (score 0):

These are two different things and need two different answers.

A class's number of students is its [**enrollment**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/enroll).  This is the number of students entered into its rolls or class list.

The fluid contained in a container is the [**volume**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/volume) of its contents.  That is, the amount of space taken by its contents within the container.

*Volume* holds validity for the contents of many items. You *could* say volume of the class. But this would be a bit strange.

Of course, the most generic term would be [*contents*](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/contents).  As this would apply to that which was contained in any capacity.

Comment: Volume sounds like the total capacity, where what I'm after is how full it currently is (out of the total).  Enrollment is correct for a class, but I'm after a general term.  The class and container were only a couple of examples where the desired word could be applied.

Comment: @jinglesthula Volume is a measure in general of the amount of something. You're speaking of the volume capacity of the container. A 100ml beaker with 50ml of water still contains a volume of 50ml of water.

Comment: true. I was conflating the volume of the contents with that of the container. What I'm after would be a property of the container rather than of the contents. In the container example, it would be "the container's ___" rather than "the ___ of the contents" (volume). The volume of the contents (say, water) would be the same whether it was in a container whose volume was equal to or double the volume of the water; but in these cases the ____ of the containers would be very different (100% vs 50%, or full vs half-full). I clarified the title to indicate I'm after a general term.

Comment: @jinglesthula see my edit.

Comment: apportionment?? It's unusual but I dare say in every blank @jingesthula has provided it could be correctly inserted. Maybe allotment would sound more acceptable, for modern usage. But I felt apportionment much more generally usable, even though it may be uncommonly leveraged to the full extent of which it could be... "Various volumes of the contents were then apportioned into different containers. Each having its own apportionment."

Answer (score 0):

**load** or **fill** can be used that way.  It's an example of the common usage of interchanging verbs and subjects of their actions.  One loads a load and fills with a fill.

Because one fills a container with liquid, the container's fill is (for example) half.

Comment: don't you think you're more re-phrasing than Answering the Question?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I can see how this answer can be taken that way.  It's not a very satisfying answer.  It does make one wish for a better word to describe the concept.  But, at least technically, it's still an answer.  These two words can be used to name the property in question.

Comment: Thanks and it took that extra debate to show me, for one, what you actually meant. Would it be too much to ask you to Edit the Posted Answer, at least re-phrasing and perhaps simply dropping "It's an example of the common usage of interchanging verbs and subjects of their actions. One loads a load and fills with a fill…"?